# How to limit from scrolling of an image (in scrollview) into the white space?

Tags: android, android-studio, scrollview

I am a beginner in Android Studio and android development in general. I want the scrollview to allow scrolling only till the end of the image but its scrolling into the white space. I tried quite a few things but I am just not getting it where I am going wrong.

[The scrollable image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eVUyb.png),
[Image showing scrolling into the white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GjAKq.png)

Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        tools:context="com.android101.chroniclesofnarutouzumaki.MainActivity">


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/naruto_uzumaki"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:id="@+id/naruto" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Never Give Up!" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
                android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="438dp"
                android:text="What to Add?" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: This got successfully resolved. Just added 'android:adjustViewBounds="true"' in the imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for getting extra whitespace in Layout is In TextView you mentioned the marginTop attribute as android:layout_marginTop="438dp" and also you didn't set adjustViewbounds to ImageView.

More Over the intention of image is to show on layout background means you can set the image as background to relative layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
   >


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/naruto"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Never Give Up!" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="What to Add?" />

    </RelativeLayout>

   </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/naruto_uzumaki"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


       <!-- <ImageView

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:id="@+id/naruto" />
-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Never Give Up!" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="438dp"
            android:text="What to Add?" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want, you need the white space to be fixed height or to be visible always(text1,text2) and only scroll the image  ,if that's the case, you need to use linear layout and inside it put a scroll view with weigh 1 and the text1 and text 2 give them height wrap content here's the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/naruto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@drawable/bassma_avatar" />
</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="Never Give Up!" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:text="What to Add?" />
```

this will make the image stretch in a way that still text1 and 2 be visible , if it's larger than this limit you will be able to scroll then

Comment: just add the missing close tag for the linear layout
</LinearLayout>